Execute Random Number Generation Once In Kotlin With Jetpack Compose
I am trying to add a random Int to another Int once for math purposes, but it seems to get new random numbers frequently instead of once. I pull an Int from an Array with a value of 45, and I want to add a random Int between 15 and 45 (say it generates 26) it would make the new value 71.
Here is what I have currently:
@Composable
fun name(
// lost of variables listed from main activity
val timeList = listOf(
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
    26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 25, 36,
    37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 42, 44, 45)
) {
if (songVar != "") {
    val index = arrayOfSongs.indexOfFirst { it[0] == songVar }
    time1m = (arrayOfSongs[index][1]).toInt()
    time1s = (arrayOfSongs[index][2]).toInt() + timeList.random()
    Log.d("random1", time1s.toString())
} else {
    time1m = 0
    time1s = 0
}

Logcat will show the value change like 10 times the first time the loop becomes true, but when I move to the next if loop, it generates anywhere from 100 times to 800 times. Which changes other numbers and math frequently.
I thought about trying to make a new Array of random numbers every time the app opens, so I can just ask for whatever value is at a certain index, but I have no idea how to do that from any examples I have looked at.


Remove @Composable as it is unnecessary for this 2. Use remember { name() } when you call this so your value is saved during recompositions


This is what I did based on @Милош Којадиновић's comment:
val rand1 = remember {
    (15..45).random()
}

This gave me an 18 the first run, and remained 18 for every subsequent run
